# How to rotate view 180 degrees

Tags: android, rotation, degrees

```
android:rotation="180"
```

Android 2.2 - 2.3 - not supported.

for example app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=example.matharithmetics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Extend the TextView class and override the onDraw method.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
     canvas.save();
     canvas.rotate(180,<appropriate x pivot value>,<appropriate y pivot value>);
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     canvas.restore();
}
```

Or using the line `myCusstomView.setRotation(180);` should work